# how to determine which Merge mode (add/ average/ multiply/ dot / concat) to use?

Tags: python, merge, keras

After testing the script of [babi_rnn.py] and [babi_memnn.py], the question of [how to determine which Merge mode (add/ average/ multiply/ dot / concat) to use?] raised up many times in my mind.

For example, for the LSTM modeling，it seems easy to understand that using [concat] to merge let's say two-branches's time sequence layer output.

However, it is not that easy for me to understand why to use [add] to merge two branches in [babi_rnn.py]. In [babi_memnn.py], the [add],[dot] and [concat] merging modes are recruited.

So, is there any suggestions for choosing which merging function to use in different usage scenarios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These Merge functions fall into 3 categories.

`add`, `avg` are linear combinations. It is used for simply combining several distinct components together because **gradient flows nicely through addition and subtraction**. A common use case is adding(+) several criterion together to obtain a loss function for a neural network that trains on multiple tasks jointly.

Another example is **L2 regularization**:
[image]

L2 regularization aims to minimize variance in weights. So the bigger the weights, the higher the loss.

---

`multiply` is a a special case of `dot`. In Keras, you can specify axis using `dot`. Dot product is used for determining how similar two or more vectors are to each other. Note: `dot` product is in fact a **shrink operation**. Its magnitude will be smaller or equal to either of the original inputs. Demonstrated geometrically as projection:

[image]

---

`concat` does not discard any input. The concatenated vector can then be fed into a hidden layer to be rescaled elementwise. You don't find the interaction between elements. One common practice is concatenating the hidden state and output of stacked RNN and feeding that into a `Dense` layer to have several RNN do different tasks similar to a feedforward network.

[image]

---

To sum up, each Merge operation has a different use case. In Luong Attention paper, there are 3 proposed scoring mechanism. Depending on your model, you can pick and choose the one that works best for you.

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! It makes this question much clearer!

Comment: It seems there is a mistake in the plotted keras model: the input shape of "keras.layers.core.Merge" should be [(None, 32), (None, 32)].

Comment: Especially you give some explainations about the underlying meaning of different Merging mode! That's great!

Comment: Can you give some more explaination about the different of `add` and `average`? for example, why dont' we use `average` instead of `add` in [babi_rnn.py]?  @Ricky Han

Comment: These should have the same effects. After some elementwise rescaling they should be exactly the same value.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!@Ricky Han